# Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm getting an error as follows:

```
Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined.
```

Component template:

```html
<input #input placeholder="Search" id="search">
<div class="item" *ngFor="let item of data | searchPipe: input.value">
  {{item}}
</div>
```

Pipe code:

```ts
@Pipe({
  name: 'searchPipe',
  pure: false
})
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(data: any[], searchTerm: string): any[] {
    searchTerm = searchTerm.toUpperCase();
    return data.filter(item => {
      return item.toUpperCase().indexOf(searchTerm) !== -1 
    });
  }
}
```

What causes the error?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since the incoming data was `null` and the `filter` method was expecting data, thus, this caused the error.

Here's a working implementation:

```ts
transform(items: any[], filterQuery: any): any[] {
  if (!filterQuery) return items;
  return items.filter(item => item.whateverProperty.toLowerCase().includes(filterQuery.toLowerCase()));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(data: any[], searchTerm: string): any[] {
    if(!data) return [];
    searchTerm = searchTerm.toUpperCase();
    return data.filter(item => {
      return item.toUpperCase().indexOf(searchTerm) !== -1 
    });
  }
}
```